# How to identify Elements using text attribute by Selenium Webdriver in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have just started working on Selenium Webdriver and wanted to try out a command that will identify any element based on the text it shows in the UI.
The HTML Structure of the attribute is shown below.

```
<div class="cuesLoginProductName">Select One</div>
```

i want to identify the div name on the Text "Select One". Can this be done in Selenium Webdriver. I have done it before in Ruby using the command 
@browser.div(:text=>'Select One').present?

Please let me know how i can identify the element.

Thanks and Regards
Sushanth.G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using xpath  `//div[text()='Select One']`

```
Driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[text()='Select One']"));
```